# Chrome crashes when trying to upload RDF files through the GraphDB dashboard

Tags: google-chrome, graphdb

A few days ago Chrome unexpectedly started to crash whenever I go to GraphDB dashboard's `Import` > `Upload RDF files`. Chrome crashes altogether the moment I press the `Upload RDF files` button. GraphDB continues to be online and nothing is logged in its logs. The issue was not resolved when I upgraded to the latest version of GraphDB.

System info:

- Google Chrome 111.0.5563.64 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- macOS Monterey 12.6, 2,6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7, 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- GraphDB Free Version 10.2.0

**EDIT #1**: I was encountering the same issue with Safari and Opera, while with Firefox everything was working fine!

**EDIT #2**: The issue with all browsers was magically resolved a few days later. No idea what happened!

Comment: It is likely due to the size of your upload. For larger uploads they recommend you to use the command line tool `$GraphDB_Home/bin/importrdf`.

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse no this is not it, as it crashes as soon as I press the button and not after choosing the file. And the file I want to choose is just a few MB big, so this is not the case.